# Spark 2.3.1 ERROR AsyncEventQueue:70 - Dropping event from queue appStatus

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

> ERROR AsyncEventQueue:70 - Dropping event from queue
>   appStatus. This likely means one of the listeners is too slow and
>   cannot keep up with the rate at which tasks are being started by the
>   scheduler.

I am using spark version 2.3.1 but I still get the error (It is believed that spark versions > 2.3.0 come handy to solve the issue). Is the size of the data causing the problem? What could be the possible solution?

I changed the size from 10000(default) to 100000 using spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size= but I fear that this has just postponed the error.

Any help would be appreciated.